# Forecasting monthly sales

Tags: time-series, forecasting

The data contains 2016 Jan- Dec and 2017 Jan-June order data for each customers. But most of the order amount is 0, that means most customers only order one or two times a year. Some of customers are new for 2017 and there are no records for these customers in 2016.

Data looks like(in dollars): 0,0,0,100,0,0,0,0,70,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

How can I forecast the order amount for each customer for July- Dec 2017?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for in called intermittent forecasting. Check out the R package `tsintermittent`.
This link will be helpful https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127337/explain-the-croston-method-of-r